# C++: How to obtain different behaviour for methods of abstract-derived classes from the derived classes of another abstract class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class, virtual-functions

I have two abstract classes, fooBase and barBase. They both have two (or more) concrete child classes (`foo1`, `foo2` and `bar1`,`bar2`). I want a method of each of the child classes of `barBase` to call a method corresponding to one of the concrete classes in `fooBase`. For example,

```
class fooBase{
    virtual int method()=0;
};

class foo1 : public fooBase {
    public :
    foo1(){}
    int method(){return 1;}
};

class foo2 : public fooBase {
    public :
    foo2(){}
    int method(){return 2;}
};

class barBase {
    virtual int drilldown(fooBase &)=0;
};

class bar1 : public barBase {
    public :
    bar1(){}
    int drilldown(foo1 & f){return f.method();}
};

class bar2 : public barBase {
    public :
    bar2(){}
    int drilldown(foo2 & f){return f.method();}
};
```

and then in main() do:

```
    foo1 f1;
    foo2 f2;
    bar1 b1;
    bar2 b2;
```

But I get the error: `Variable type 'b1' is an abstract class` (likewise for b2). I know that this is happening because the method `drilldown` in `barBase` is defined with a parameter that is a reference to the `fooBase` abstract class but bar1 and bar2 are trying to drill down into the concrete child classes so compiler doesn't recognise that the method for `drilldown(fooBase &)` is defined in the child classes. How can I fix this so that I get the behaviour that I want? What is the right design pattern for this situation?

---

I ended up using the solution by Joachim Pileborg (see below). I also had to change any functions with arguments     barBase &, to template functions i.e.,

```
 template<class T>
 int fn(barBase<T> & b, T & f){
    return b.drilldown(f);
 }


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    foo1 f1;
    foo2 f2;
    bar1 b1;
    bar2 b2;
    std::cout<<b1.drilldown(f1);
    fn(b1,f1);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define the `bar`s as a class template and instantiations, rather than a polymorphic hierarchy?

Comment: @Sambuca, yes I realise that.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, can u give me a little more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `barBase` as a template, like

```
template<typename T>
struct barBase {
    virtual int drilldown(T &)=0;
};

class bar1 : public barBase<foo1> {
    public :
    bar1(){}
    int drilldown(foo1 & f){return f.method();}
};

class bar2 : public barBase<foo2> {
    public :
    bar2(){}
    int drilldown(foo2 & f){return f.method();}
};
```

Of course it has the drawback that you can't use pointers or references to `barBase` to refer to either of its child classes.

Comment: Which reduces the genericity of the base-class considerable. Why not go full CRTP?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I want barBase to refer to child classes. For example, if I have a function int f(barBase & b, fooBase & f){return b.drilldown(f);}, I want the behaviour f(bar1 b,f)=1 and f(bar2 b,f)=2.

Comment: @Deduplicator, could you give more info on CRTP? can I use it to keep the barBase class general and still refer to the child classes as I've written for example in the comment above?

Comment: "you can't use barBase to refer to either of its child classes". That's not really a drawback. You won't be able to do anything useful with `barBase`, except casting it back to one of the bars.

Comment: @JaseUknow What if you have `b` referring to `bar1` and `f` referring to `foo2`? what's the meaning of `b.drilldown(f)`?

Comment: @n.m, For what it's worth, foo is a uniform random number generator, and bar is a distribution. I want bar.drilldown(f), to select the appropriate/best generator for the particular distribution, bar, and return a random sample from that distribution.  I want to be able to use the same source code, but have freedom to change rng's and distributions by instantiating the objects in the code accordingly.

Comment: If you want `drilldown` to automatically select the best generator (out of what set of generators?), why are you passing it one single generator? There's nothing about selection of the best candidate in the original Q. Don't you think it's a completely different question?

Comment: @n.m sorry bad wording. I don't want it to automatically select anything. I want bar.drilldown(f), to return a random sample from the distribution, bar, using the uniform random variable f. I have a particular distribution, call this normal, that I always only want to use a particular uniform random number generator, urng. So when I make the concrete class, normal, I want the drilldown method to go to the concrete urng class. Yes, maybe this is a different question, but I thought the problem I have reduces to solving the question I have asked.

Comment: I got my code working using this solution, in the end I used template classes mentioned in this solution and I also had to template the functions.I suppose this is the solution to the question I asked about the right design pattern. I'm surprised though that there isn't a way to do this using polymorphism.

Comment: Well, templates *are* a kind of polymorphism and arguably the most important one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you only need:

```
class barBase {
    int drilldown(fooBase &f){ return f.method(); }
};
```

and your supposed function:

```
int f(barBase & b, fooBase & f){return b.drilldown(f);}
```

will work just fine.

Comment: this is nice, but I really need the different bar child classes, they have other methods with different implementations which distinguishes them, not just through drilldown. Thanks anyway.